# Post preview in iframe without saving the post

Tags: posts, wp-admin, previews, iframe

I aim to make a live preview inside an iframe of the current edit post. The preview should render the post content only. That's why I guess an iframe is actually a good idea. The frontend includes [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) for the content style. So the iframe will inlcude `wp_head()` to load the styles.

So my questions are:

- Is it possible to get the editor content, parse all shortcodes and load it into an iframe with `wp_head()` content?
- How to programmatically open a custom iframe in the admin post edit page? Is there an API for it?

Comment: The default template function `get_the_content()` get the formated content, usable also in your custom preview.

Comment: But than I have to save the post, right?

Comment: No, a other post status is also possible. The save is always required.